# Local Notification with sound downloaded from the internet - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios5

I want to make a local push notification with a sound that the user will download from the internet.

The problem is that the sound must be saved in the main bundle according to apple documentation. Moreover i read that it is impossible to write programatically on the main Bundle.

Does anybody have any idea on how to overcome this issue? It cannot be impossible to make such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it has to be in the app's bundle is so that is can be used without having to run any code in your app and Apple doesn't have to worry about it ever being missing. You cannot overcome this issue on an app sold in the official App Store.